# how do I create a function in R to accept both NULL and Non-NULL values of parameters when using tidyverse?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, tidyverse, quotes

I want to create a function whereby if I enter the name of a grouping variable in a tibble to be NULL I want the function to output the number of entire rows in the tibble.  However, if I enter the name of a grouping variable/s, the output will be the number of rows according to the grouping variables.  When I try the code below, the function only works if col_name parameter is NULL.  How do I get this function to work if I enter a valid grouping variable/s?

```
library(tidyverse)

tib <- tibble( 

          colB = sample(c("A", "B"), 50, replace = T), 
          colC = sample(c("C", "D"), 50, replace = T),
          colD = sample(c("C", "D"), 50, replace = T)
          )

 

    test_fun <- function(df, col_name = NULL, ...){
                         
                 if(is.null(col_name)){
                            count(df)
                          } else 
                        {
                           
                            y <- enquo(col_name) 
                            z <- enquos(...)
                            
                            df %>%
                             count(!!y, !!!z) 
                          }
                    }
            
test_fun(df = tib) #- works
test_fun(df = tib, col_name = colB, colC) # does not work
```

Comment: If you use the base `is.null`, it will evaluate the lazy parameter then you can't capture it any more. Use `rlang::quo_is_null` after you've turned it into a quosure to get it to work. See duplicate question for a working example. You could rewrite your function as `test_fun <- function(df, col_name = NULL, ...){y <- enquo(col_name) ; if(rlang::quo_is_null(y)) { count(df) } else { count(df, !!y, ...) } }`

Comment: Using the curly curly operator would probably work here, with something like this inside your function: `df |> group_by({{ col_name }}) |>  count()`

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Just found the solution. test_fun <- function(df, ...){/n z <- enquos(...) /n df %>% count(!!!z) /n } . If no variable entered as a parameter for ..., then function count evaluated without a variable.